# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]' error in stream builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting following error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'
[The part where error is coming is highlighted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzOnN.png)

The code for stream is this

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Users')
                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                    .collection('Coins')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  return ListView(

                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                      return Container(
                        
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            
                            Text("Coin type: ${document.id}"),
                            
                            Text("Amount Owned: ${document.data()!['Amount']}"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as Map?`

```dart
Text(
    "Amount Owned: ${(document.data() as Map?)?['Amount']}"),
```

More about [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) and [reading data from firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Comment: Yes it worked thanks can you explian me please why it worked :)

Comment: `data()` returns `Object?` datatype, while it is map we know, we are using `as` prefix , telling compiler it is  `Map?` .. `?` means nullable dataType

Comment: why we have to write it as map? when i previously write it as map it was giving error

Comment: It is safe to use making nullable dataType,when we dont know what it will return(IMO),